# Подключить libcurl к проекту в MinGW Studio

Tags: c, curl, ide, mingw

Я скачал библиотеку `curl` для `win32`. Там есть библиотека с расширением `.a`. Как ее подключить к проекту? Я использую `MinGW Studio`

Comment: Там откуда скачали руководства к использованию разве нет?

Comment: Какой проект? Какая система сборки?

Comment: Как понять какой проект? личный проект. Собираю под win 32. Просто сам файл, я скачал curl там были заголовочные файлы, я их перекинул, далее еше были файлы с расширением .a, вот как их в MinGW Studio присоединить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое, что нужно сделать, после распаковки архива с библиотекой - указать дополнительные пути, по которым компилятор сможет найти её заголовочные файлы, а линковщик - саму библиотеку. Соответственно, в архиве должны быть как минимум вот эти папки, со всеми необходимыми файлами внутри:

```
bin\      - *.dll
include\  - *.h
lib\      - *.a
```

Для MinGW могу порекомендовать вот этот репозиторий:

- curl: https://bintray.com/vszakats/generic/curl#files
- openssl: https://bintray.com/vszakats/generic/openssl#files

Пути можно указывать либо через глобальные настройки `Edit - Options - Directories`, либо, в каждом проекте и в каждой конфигурации (`Debug`/`Release`) отдельно, через `Project - Settings`:

- на вкладке `Compile`, в `Additional include directories` нужно прописать полный путь к `include` папке:

[image: Вкладка Compile]

- на вкладке `Link`, в `Additional library path` - полный путь к папке `lib`:

[image: Вкладка Link]

И наконец, на вкладке `Link`, в поле `Libraries` нужно прописать название линкуемой библиотеки, *без приставки `lib` и без расширения*. Т.е. если на диске файл лежит под именем `libcurldll.a`, то мы должны записать его как `curldll`.

После этого можно собирать проект. А чтобы собранный `exe` запустился, рядом с ним должны находиться зависимые `dll`: `libcurl.dll`, `libcrypto-1_1.dll`, `libssl-1_1.dll` (либо, они должны находиться в `PATH`).

И кстати, MinGW Studio нужна с GCC 4.8.1 и в настройках компиляции обязательно нужно указать флаг `-std=c99`. Иначе, ничего не скомпилируется.