# Статическая линковка libcurl в MinGW

Tags: c, curl, codeblocks, lib

Добрый день господа. Пытаюсь подключить `libcurl.a` к проекту в Code::Blocks MinGW. Скинул заголовки в include и .a файл в lib, прописываю линк, `#define` и параметр `-static` но ничего не происходит, как была ошибка мол `curl_easy_init()` не найдено, так и есть.

Так вот, есть ли где-нибудь подробная инструкция подключения именно статических библиотек к проекту Си.

Comment: Залинкуйте его через саму среду.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862757/how-do-i-link-to-a-library-with-codeblocks

Comment: Так беда в том, что я так и делаю. Вот скрин - https://pp.vk.me/c637821/v637821670/10747/dFvgb5SKj7E.jpg

Comment: Можете попробовать запустить свою программу и заскринить (через PrintScreen) место вывода ошибок?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Особенность подключения статических библиотек состоит в том, чтобы, помимо подключения самой библиотеки, подключить и все её зависимости, которые, в свою очередь, можно подключать как статические библиотеки, так и как dll.

Что касается именно `libcurl`, то в зависимости от опций, с которыми она была скомпилирована, эта библиотека может зависеть от целой кучи сторонних библиотек (помимо системных).

Как я уже рекомендовал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/569928/curl-%D0%B2-mingw-%D0%A1%D0%B8?rq=1), собранную `libcurl` и её зависимости можно найти вот в этом репозитории: https://bintray.com/vszakats/generic

Для статической линковки этой версии `curl` понадобятся ещё 3 библиотеки из того репозитория: `libssh2`, `nghttp2`, `openssl`. Так же, для сборки понадобится `zlib`. Для сборки всех библиотек используется [MinGW-w64 версии 6.2.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/6.2.0), которая в своём составе имеет и `zlib`, так что рекомендую взять эту же версию.

Чтобы проект в Code::Blocks был переносимым, указанные библиотеки и их заголовочники лучше всего копировать не в директорию MinGW, а куда-то в пределах папки с проектом (например, в папки `lib` и `include`).

Далее, надо открыть настройки проекта `Project - Build options` и прописать:

- на вкладке `Compiler settings - #defines`: `CURL_STATICLIB`
- на вкладке `Search Directories - Compiler`: `include` - относительный/абсолютный путь к заголовочникам (`.h`) библиотек
- на вкладке `Search Directories - Linker`: `lib` - относительный/абсолютный путь к либам (`.a` файлам) библиотек
- на вкладке `Linker settings - Link libraries`: `curl`, `ssl`, `crypto`, `ssh2`, `nghttp2`, `z`, `ws2_32`, `winmm`, `wldap32`, `crypt32` - линкуемые библиотеки. ***Тут очень важно соблюдать порядок, в котором библиотеки будут линковаться!***

Вот, собственно, и всё, можно собирать:

```
gcc.exe -Wall -O2 -DCURL_STATICLIB -std=c99 -m32 --static -static-libgcc -Iinclude -IC:\dev\mingw-w64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include -c B:\cb_curl_static\main.c -o obj\Release\main.o
gcc.exe -Llib -LC:\dev\mingw-w64\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\lib -o bin\Release\cb_curl_static.exe obj\Release\main.o  -s -m32 --static -static-libgcc  -lcurl -lssl -lcrypto -lssh2 -lnghttp2 -lz -lws2_32 -lwinmm -lwldap32 -lcrypt32
Output file is bin\Release\cb_curl_static.exe with size 2.68 MB
```

В итоге, получился довольно большой `exe` файл, но он зависит только от системных библиотек.

Comment: А если к примеру мне не нужна поддержка ссл, следовательно крипто наверное тоже отпадает, вес сучественно уменьшится?

Comment: @Corle Да, но для этого надо перекомпилировать `libcurl` с отключением `ssl`, `ssh` и `http2`.