# Не могу установить библиотеку cURL в Code::Blocks + MinGw

Tags: c++, curl, codeblocks, библиотека

Я довольно новичок в c++. Возникла необходимость установить либу **cURL** в **Code::Blocks**. Почитав в сети, я понял, что это можно сделать, если:

- A) Установить в `compiler -> search directories -> compiler` папку
  `include` с хедерами
- B) Добавить в `compiler -> linker` файл `libcurl.a`

Взял для примера такой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "curl/curl.h"
#define CURL_STATIC

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
    /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      cout << "curl_easy_perform() failed: " << curl_easy_strerror(res) << endl;

    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
    return 0;
}
```

Проблема в том, что после этих действий при компиляции появляется бесчисленное число ошибок по типу:

```
||=== Build: Debug in [ИМЯ ПРОЕКТА] (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
...\curl-7.69.0-win32-mingw\curl-7.69.0-win32-mingw\lib\libcurl.a(connect.o)|| undefined reference to `_imp__ntohs@4'|
...\curl-7.69.0-win32-mingw\curl-7.69.0-win32-mingw\lib\libcurl.a(connect.o)|| undefined reference to `_imp__getpeername@12'|
...\curl-7.69.0-win32-mingw\curl-7.69.0-win32-mingw\lib\libcurl.a(connect.o)|| undefined reference to `_imp__WSAGetLastError@0'|
```

На самом деле их больше сорока.

После долгих поисков в сети я наткнулся на один ответ (уже не помню, где):
В `compiler -> linker` нужно поместить **два** файла:

1. `libcurl.a`
2. `libcurl.dll.a`

Окей, все скомпилировалось, НО при запуске программы через C::B (Компиляция и запуск) появляется диалог со следующей ошибкой: `Ошибка при запуске приложения (0xc00000be). Для выхода из приложения нажмите "ОК".`
Есть еще одно замечание:
Если я запущу программу из файла, который генерирует C::B, то тоже появится ошибка, но содержания, что на компьютере отсутствует `libcurl.dll`. Ладно, ее я нашел в архиве с cURL, кинул в директорию с программой. Теперь — ошибка, что нет `libcrypto-1_1.dll`. Я без понятия, где брать эту библиотеку.

**P.S.**

Сейчас я понял, что установил не ту разрядность библиотеки (32). Я ее переустановил и сделал все то же самое. Теперь у меня другая ошибка =)

```
||=== Build: Debug in [Имя проекта] (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
:(.text.startup+0x2f)||undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'|
:(.text.startup+0x4d)||undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'|
:(.text.startup+0x65)||undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'|
:(.text.startup+0x6d)||undefined reference to `curl_easy_perform'|
:(.text.startup+0x91)||undefined reference to `curl_easy_strerror'|
:(.text.startup+0xad)||undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 7 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Примечания:

1. Сам хедер C::B находит.
2. При попытке установки флага curl в линковщике ошибка: `ld.exe||cannot find -lcurl|`.

**Буду очень благодарен видео-туториалу, как это сделать: так все будет наиболее наглядно.**

---

Установлен MinGw.

Установлен Gcc. Сведения о версии:

```
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.1.0 (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
```

Установлен Code::Blocks версии `17.12`.

Библиотека cURL версии `curl-7.69.0-win64-mingw` ([ссылка на архив](https://curl.haxx.se/windows/dl-7.69.0/curl-7.69.0-win64-mingw.zip)). Архив распакован в произвольную директорию.

Windows 7 (64-разрядная)

В настройках компилятора указана статическая компиляция

Comment: Неужели никто не знает?

Comment: Дубль: [Статическая линковка libcurl в MinGW](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/580168/177722)

Comment: *"compiler -> linker нужно поместить два файла"* Нет, нужен только один. Первый для статической линковки, второй для динамической. Лучше оставьте второй. *"понял, что установил не ту разрядность библиотеки. Я ее переустановил"* Нет, разрядность была правильная. Теперь вы поставили неправильную.

Comment: *"Теперь ошибка что нет libcrypto-1_1.dll"* У меня она лежит в папке bin компилятора. Но я GCC ставил из MSYS2, так что у вас ее может там не быть, проверьте.

Comment: вот честно не понимаю зачем Вы сами себе усложняет жизнь, зачем под Windows использовать mingw gcc? когда есть clang и бесплатная VS2019 и по поводу curl советую погуглить Conan.io он упростит вам жизнь не только с curl

Comment: @Arenoros Ради кроссплатформенности? Да и с поддержкой разных редких фич языка у MSVC не очень. А библиотеки и там и там подключаются легко, просто уметь надо.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, у нас разработка идёт под 20+ различных платформ и вся основная разработка идёт под vs, для всех стальных платформ тупо makefile один написан

Comment: @zed скоро попробую этот ответ в действии

Comment: @Arenoros а чем MinGw усложняет что-то? Я не в курсе просто

Comment: @cppcat, gcc  не родной компилятор для win32 из-за чего могут возникать некоторые проблемы с предсобранными либами. По моему очевидно что "родной" компилятор работает стабильнее. К тому же с vs это хоть как то приближается к разработке на Linux, в том плане что ни чего не нужно настраивать для его работы. И уж точно VS гораздо удобнее чем codeblocks. Я как бы не вижу ни одной вменяемой причины почему стоит использовать codeblocks с GCC

Comment: @Arenoros есть причина использовать code blocks - небольшое количество потребляемых ресурсов. Просто компьютер у меня не особо мощный